# How to get the speadsheet id of an embedded table in google slide with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-slides

I wrote a small Google Apps Script Addon for Google Presentation which looks for embedded Google Charts from a spreadsheet and duplicates this spreadsheet.
It gets all [SheetCharts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide?hl=de#getsheetscharts) which have a [Method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart?hl=de#getspreadsheetid) to get the ID of the spreadsheet.

```
  var newSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage().asSlide();
var allCharts = newSlide.getSheetsCharts();
for(var i = 0; i < allCharts.length; i++){
   chartInfos.push({
     chartSheet:allCharts[i],
     sourceSheetId: allCharts[i].getSpreadsheetId()
   })
  }
```

This works pretty well, however now I want to do the exact same thing with embedded tables from a spreadsheet. On the Slides class there is a [getTables](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide?hl=de#gettables) which gives you an array of all [Tables](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table) in that slide, however there is no method to get the spreadsheet id of that table..

So my question is how to get the underlying spreadsheet id of a table which was added from a spreadsheet to a slide?

Comment: Agree, there's no method available to get the spreadsheet ID of the embedded table from slide using Apps Script. This is a brilliant idea to add for future use! If you have the time, you can submit it here: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762)

Comment: I created a google support ticket not sure if this is the same ;)

Comment: for completion there is already an item in the google issue tracker from 2017
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64027131